# Are express route variables re-initialized every time a new request is received?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have this route in my node express app that receives post requests from my angular 5 frontend. See the post request below where I initialize 3 variables with empty strings.

```
app.post('/rolecompare', function (req, res) {

var inputfilerolecompare1 = '';
var inputfilerolecompare2 = '';
var filenametowrite = '';
```

//using multer middleware I access the uploaded files and assign the inputfilerolecompare1 and inputfilerolecompare2 with full input file path and name to store the files on my server. Thereafter I use these variables inside the app.post method to import data to mongodb from the files and run some python scripts on them to write an output file.

Question: While this is going on lets say my app.post receives another request and the inputfilerolecompare1 = '', inputfilerolecompare2 = '', filenametowrite = '' are reinitialized again how does that affect the first request still being processed. Will the first request now start referencing the new assignments?

Thanks for helping me understand this better.

Comment: No. Second request does not affect the first request in your case.Each request will initialize their own variables.

Comment: No, another request will not affect the one that is executed. This is because function local variables are never shared in any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each incoming request will have it's own `request` and `response` objects and what you modify in one request object will have nothing to do with another request.  They are completely separate in that regard.

Further, variables declared local to the request handler such as your `inputfilerolecompare1` are also completely separate for each request.  Each request is its own function call so each function gets its own new set of local variables just like regular function calls.

> While this is going on lets say my app.post receives another request and the `inputfilerolecompare1 = '', inputfilerolecompare2 = '', filenametowrite = ''` are reinitialized again how does that affect the first request still being processed.

These variables are local variables to one specific request.  Because they are declared as local variables (local to the request handler function), they are separate variables with separate values for each request.  What you set them to in one request has nothing to do with another request.

> Will the first request now start referencing the new assignments?

No.  Each request has its own copy of these variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Appreciate your help.